# Using IMPORTRANGE() with an array of spreadsheet_key

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I am trying to import data from a few Spreadsheets using IMPORTRANGE(), however having every spreadsheet_key inline would make it a pain to read, a pain to add a new key. I am trying to load the spreadsheet_keys from a list, something like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE({Settings!A30:A31}, "Test!A2:V")
```

where `Settings!A30` holds a key and `Settings!A31` holds a second key.

I don't get any errors, but it only loads data from the first spreadsheet!

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: There is a 3rd party script which (I believe) allows you to do this:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/6lczh2QEEXQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are taking is sound, but the `:A31` in your formula is being ignored. (Presumably the key that works for you is the one in `A30` and not the one in `A31`.) This makes sense to me because I would not expect Google to know which data from which set to put in which cell where the two datasets are competing for occupation of the same range.

You may just need to ensure the formulae are in cells not already occupied - and with enough room for expansion for the imported data. So maybe:

```
=IMPORTRANGE({Settings!A30},"Test!A2:V")
```

in one cell and, once that data is imported, choose a cell below those then occupied and insert there:

```
=IMPORTRANGE({Settings!A31},"Test!A2:V")
```